# CSS - Manipulate another element on hover

Tags: html, css

I need to change #hidden to `display:block` when `#aaa` is hovered over. It's not working because `#aaa` isn't on the same level as `#hidden` - is there a way to manipulate a completely separate element on hover? I'm trying to make a CSS-based nav w/ a subnav and show the respective subnav when a nav item is hovered over.

HTML:

```
<div class="cheetahContainer">
    <div id="cheetah">
       <p><a href="#">Cheetah</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="hidden">
       <p>A cheetah is a land mammal that can run up 2 60mph!!!</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#cheetah {
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
}

a {
    color: blue;
}

#hidden {
    display:none;
    color: orange;
 }
#cheetah:hover{
    background-color:green;
}

#cheetah:hover + #hidden {
    display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LgKkU/575/

Comment: I would just move the `#hidden` into the `class="cheetahContainer"` and then you can manipulate it in CSS the way were doing it - see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LgKkU/576/).

Comment: If you are making a navigation element why not use ul/li?

Comment: Sorry yes I'm using a ul/li in my real code, I just grabbed a jsfiddle that was working with direct siblings but not with this layout.

Answer (score 1):

Since your link is not a sibling of your `#hidden` div (thus you can't use the immediate adjacency selector), you should change last rule with

```
.cheetahContainer:hover + #hidden {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: I wish but no, the #cheetah actually represents a nav item and therefore the CSS rule needs to be specific to the #cheetah.

Comment: then you should post the markup you _actually_ use, otherwise answers may not be useful - my answer just solve your issue as you have described it.

Answer (score 1):

Hovering over an element can only affect child elements in css. Here's a fix for your example:

```
<div class="cheetahContainer">
    <div id="cheetah">
       <p><a href="#">Cheetah</a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="hidden">
           <p>A cheetah is a land mammal that can run up 2 60mph!!!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, I would recommend changing the css to something like this:

```
.cheetahContainer:hover .hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

Changed out id's for classes and added hover to parent element so that hovering over the revealed text doesn't revert back to display:none;

Comment: @Harry yes, sorry for not making it clearer, I was recommending switching to a class instead of an id. I assume there might be more than one hidden element on that page so I thought a class would be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a direct sibling so you need to use js

Here is an example of what to do:

```
var $cheetah = document.getElementById('cheetah');
var $hidden = document.getElementById('hidden');
$cheetah.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    $hidden.style.display = 'block';
});
$cheetah.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    $hidden.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Or you can use the container:

```
.cheetarContainer:hover + #hidden {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Two small corrections mate, `cheetahContainer` has a typo (`r` instead of `h`) and it is a `class` in this case not an `id`.